# Is there any modification of the Chromium for full access to local files?

Tags: javascript, chromium

I have read several docs of restriction of browsers for JavaScirpt and questions such as [question from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript), [user selected access for local files](https://web.dev/file-system-access/). Eventually, I have found out that there is no way to full access to build one-user-spa applications using Vue js, and it is true that the browsers must have restriction for JavaScript due to security when the script is download from remote server. But in my case, I want that my application is run locally (all scripts files must been in local computer) by one user and there aren't any security restriction for script. For example, my script must have full access local files and folders to manage local data base like sqlite. How can I do that?

Comment: Use a backend like Node.js

Comment: [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/) was basically made for this.